# Release memory for Custom User control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, memory, garbage-collection

I have a **live Tile user control** used inside Windows Phone app. I am using 10 instances of the control in a XAML page (initialized from code). When I navigate back to parent XAML page, the memory allocated for all 10 tile controls don't get deallocated.

The RAM usage for the child page with 10 live Tile is 60 MB. When I navigate back to parent page, the memory shoots upto 120 MB and `Garbage collector does not reduce memory usage`.

Moreover, after 2-3 page navigations, the app Memory usage shoots to `180 MB` and crashes.

How do I destroy this `usercontrol`? It has 2 `Grid`, one with `Image` and 4 `Storyboard` which get called in a loop. I got the control from [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/windows-phone-xaml-create-3707b497). Also, I have a `Tap` event controller attached to it.

**Update**

I implement a custom method in user control to destroy. Still, this doesnot deallocate memory.

```
public void destroyImage()
    {
        Storyboard anim1 = (Storyboard)FindName("liveTileAnim1_Part1");
        anim1.Stop();
        Storyboard anim2 = (Storyboard)FindName("liveTileAnim1_Part2");
        anim2.Stop();
        Storyboard anim3 = (Storyboard)FindName("liveTileAnim2_Part1");
        anim3.Stop();
        Storyboard anim4 = (Storyboard)FindName("liveTileAnim2_Part2");
        anim4.Stop();
        (this.image1.Source as BitmapImage).UriSource = null;
        (this.image1.Source) = null;
        this.image1 = null;
    }
```

Comment: If you use a collection of these controls then they will not be disposed of as long as they are in the collection. The Garbage collector will collect any objects that do not have any living connections to them so also check that you don't have any handlers (or anything else) attached to them. You should search online for further advice on this very common subject.

Comment: Where should I detach the event handlers? How will I know when the object is going to be destroyed?

Comment: That's up to you... detach them when you've finished using them... maybe when you remove them from the collection, or have no further use for it. It will be destroyed when there are no living references that point to it left.